# Multiple webpack entries and chunkFilename

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

How can I use a `[name]` placeholder inside of the `chunkFilename` key in the webpack configuration?

I am using mutliple entries like this:

```
entry: {
  path1: "file1.js",
  path2: "file2.js"
},
output: {
  path: "/dist/bundle",
  publicPath: "/dist/",
  filename: "[name].js",
  chunkFilename: "[name]/[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js"
}
```

I would expect the `chunkFilename` to appear under `path1/id.chunkhash.chunk.js` and also under `path2/id.chunkhash.chunk.js` (because the name will be the key from entry object). What it does however is it replaces both name and id with `0`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Webpack async chunks by default have no name, unless you add webpackChunkName to the import, i.e: `import(/*webpackChunkName: "test123"*/ './test.js')`.

If you don't manually do this, the default "name" for each async chunk is the id, which is the same as `[id]`. That is why it is happening.